# @PreAuthorize does not work on Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I implemented spring security 3.2.5 but unfortunately @PreAuthorize does not work on classes and methods. As I read from the documentations, @PreAuthorize should allow methods and classes to work if user has specified role inside the annotation but I am able to run all the methods or classes without any difference of roles. You can see security-config.xml and security.context.xml and my class where  I declared @PreAuthorize annotation below. I would be glad if you can help me about this problem.

security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<http pattern="/securityNone" security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />


<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="alperk" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER"  />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

security-context.xml

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    /spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="defaultAuthEventPublisher"     class="org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher"/>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="authenticationProvider"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationEventPublisher" ref="defaultAuthEventPublisher"/>
</bean>
<!-- Authentication service reference -->
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="tr.com.sistek.utak.authentication.AuthenticationUserDetailsService"/>

<!-- Authentication yapilirken MD5 password sifreleme kullaniliyor -->
 <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
    <!--<property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>-->
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="tr.com.sistek.utak.authentication.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/faces/private/MainMenu.jsf"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/login-failure.jsf?err=HATALI_PWD</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/change-password.jsf</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/login-failure.jsf?err=HESAP_KILITLI</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException">/login-failure.jsf?err=HESAP_PASIF</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <property name="errorPage" value="/error401.jsf"/>
</bean> 

<!-- Login Esnasinda Girilen Bilgileri Kontrol Etmek Icin Kullanilmistir -->
<bean id="customPreAuthenticationLoginHandler" class="tr.com.sistek.utak.authentication.CustomPreAuthenticationLoginHandler">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_security_check" />

    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />

    <property name="postOnly" value="false" />
</bean>

<sec:http pattern="/assets/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/themes/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none"/>

<sec:global-method-security             
    pre-post-annotations="enabled"
    mode="aspectj"
    proxy-target-class="true">
</sec:global-method-security>


<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  
          authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">  


    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <sec:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customPreAuthenticationLoginHandler"/>

    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsf" 
                    authentication-failure-handler-ref = "authenticationFailureHandler"
                    default-target-url="/faces/private/MainMenu.jsf"/>

    <sec:access-denied-handler ref = "accessDeniedHandler"/>

    <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" 
                logout-success-url="/login.jsf" 
                logout-url="/logout"/>

    <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsf" session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>

    <sec:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />

</sec:http>


<bean id="jsfRedirectStrategy" class="tr.com.sistek.utak.jsf.filter.JsfRedirectStrategy"/>

<bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/>

<!-- Authentication logout handler -->
<bean id="customAuthenticationLogoutHandler" class="tr.com.sistek.utak.authentication.CustomAuthenticationLogoutHandler"/>

<!-- ******************************************************************* -->
<!-- Concurrent Session Management Configuration-->
<!-- ******************************************************************* -->
<bean id="concurrencyFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.jsf" />
    <!-- this permits redirection to session timeout page from javascript/ajax or http -->
    <property name="redirectStrategy" ref="jsfRedirectStrategy" />
</bean>

<bean id="sas" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
   <!--        <property name="alwaysCreateSession" value="true" />
    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />-->
</bean>

<bean id="sessionRegistry"
      class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

Bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public class OrderDetView implements Serializable {
```

......

Comment: How are you invoking the methods in OrderDetView

Answer (score 1):

*This is only my first thought:*

Your annotations `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped` indicate that you use a JSF Framework and maybe your `OrderDetView`  bean ins just a JSF bean but not a Spring bean. But `@PreAuthorize` works only for Spring beans.

Comment: Exactly Ralph. Sorry for my mistake. I am changingg my question right now. Is it possible to use @PreAuthorize at JSF bean( I guess it is not I asked it to make sure ) or convert it to use such kind of methadology ? I would be very happy if you can assist me

Comment: You can make it work for any class but that requires AspectJ and compile time weaving of the security aspects.

Comment: Hello Deinum . As I understand from your stance you say use AspectJ with JSF Managed Bean without converting your bean to Spring Managed Bean. Can you provide a sample for using AspectJ for a Jsf Managed Bean?